# How to reduce a string expression like "20hc+2a+2hc+9op" to "22hc+2a+9op"

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, loops, filter

How to find and pair the alphabets after the numbers in a string in order to reduce one expression?

Lets assume we have a string like `string = "20hc+2a+2hc+9op+330o+10op"`, and we want to find the pair which same alphabet after numbers. First we should do `split.('+')` and then we get an array `[....]`, then we need to pair each alphabets after the numbers, to get something like below:

`(20hc + 2hc) (2a) (9op+10op) (330o)`

Finally, we need to sum the numbers for the matching pairs:

```
20+2 = 22hc
2 = 2a
9+10 = 19op
330 = 330o
```

To get a final result of:

```
22hc+2a+19op+330o
```

So, how can I approach this, it does not matter if they aren't sorted as long as the alphabet after numbers are same, in this case, could we use regex to `match` them ? or `indexOf` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for readability, just use an indexOf pair conversion, and build a hash. For example:

```js
const getPair = str => {
  const numbers = '0123456789'
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(numbers.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) < 0){ break }
  }
  return [str.slice(i), i === 0 ? 1 : parseInt(str.slice(0, i))]
}
  
//const eq = '20hc+2a+2hc+9op+330o+10op'
const eq = 'a+2ab+3b+4c+5bc'

const hash = eq.split('+')
               .map(getPair)
               .reduce((r, [key, val]) => {
                 r[key] = r[key] ? r[key] + val : val
                 return r
               }, {})

const result = Object.entries(hash).map(([key, val]) => `${val}${key}`).join('+')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: if the alphabet just a, it should be 1a, and i create another a in string, the result `NaNa`

Comment: this `'a+2ab+3b+4c+5bc'`

Comment: updated. it just needed an extra catch in the pair function.

Answer (score 2):

I will do this in **two steps**. The first step generates an object with the `keys` (alphabet letters) and the `totals` (sum of numbers) for each `key`. For this, we use [String::split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array::reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in that order. An example of the generated object will be like:

```
{"hc": 22, "op": 19, ...}
```

The second step just formats the previous generated object to the desired output string. For this one we use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array::map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and finally [Array::join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
const input = "a+20hc+2a+2hc+9op+330o+10op";

// First, get keys and sum their total.

let res = input.split("+")
    .reduce((acc, curr) =>
    {
        let [match, val, key] = curr.match(/(\d*)(\w*)/);
        val = +val || 1;
        acc[key] = acc[key] ? acc[key] + val : val;
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(res);

// Now, format to the output string.

res = Object.entries(res).map(([x, y]) => y + x).join("+");
console.log(res);
```

However, you should note that the previous approach won't work if you have `subtractions`, but some minor changes can do the work:

```js
const input = "-4a+20hc+2a+2hc+9op+330o+10op-340o";

// First, get keys and sum their total.

let res = input.split(/\+|(?=-)/)
    .reduce((acc, curr) =>
    {
        let [match, val, key] = curr.match(/(-*\d*)(\w*)/);
        val = +val || 1;
        acc[key] = acc[key] ? acc[key] + val : val;
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(res);

// Now, format to the output string.

res = Object.entries(res)
    .map(([x, y]) => y + x)
    .join("+")
    .replace(/\+-/, "-");

console.log(res);
```